# PrimeNG + Angular: Reset common data table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am working on angular 5 and primeNg. My code uses primeNg `<p-dataTable>`. In one of my components, I have 2 data tables, hence I am using a common data table component, like below:

CR common data table

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-cr-table',
      template: `
        Top Table
        <p-dataTable [value]="data" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" #dt>
        <p-header>List of Cars</p-header>
        <p-column field="name" header="Name" [filter]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="age" header="Age" [filter]="true"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>

        Bottom Table
        <p-dataTable [value]="data" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" #dt1>
        <p-header>List of Cars</p-header>
        <p-column field="name" header="Name" [filter]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="age" header="Age" [filter]="true"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
      `
    })
    })

export class BankAccountComponent {
@ViewChild('dt') crTable: DataTable;
@ViewChild('dt1') crTable1: DataTable;
```

First component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-table',
  template: `
    <app-cr-table [data]='data'></app-cr-table>
  `
})
```

Second component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-second-table',
  template: `
    <app-cr-table [data]='data'></app-cr-table>
  `
})
```

Now my requirement is to reset the second(bottom) table only, on click of a button in 1st (upper) table. Can anyone please guide me how to reset only second (bottom) table and not first?  I know there is a `reset()` function which resets the table but it resets both the tables.  I just want the second (bottom) table to reset. Please guide me.

reference: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Comment: If you are creating two table in a single component. You should have two different references one #dt second should be #dt2 or whatever you want to use.

Comment: @DirtyMind, tried doing so still did not work. No error though and below table still does not refresh

Comment: What do you mean by that? You mean to say whatever you kept in filter is not getting reset and also Paginator as well ?

Comment: also tell me how you are trying to reset the table. Can you show the code where you created the button and which method it is calling?